# PHP handle time value over 24:00H

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I'm addditioning time value of a schedule.
When The value go over 24:00 I'm begining to have a problem..

Here is a simple example of what i'm trying to do.

```
$now = strtotime("TODAY");
$time_1 = strtotime('08:00:00') - $now;
$total = $time_1 * 5;
$total = $total + $now;
echo date('H:i', $total);
```

The echo value is `16:00:00`
But it should be `40:00:00`

```
24:00:00 + 16:00:00 = 40:00:00
```

So I understand that this is 1 day and 16 hours.

How can I echo `40:00:00`

Comment: general tip: `strtotime('today')` might as well just be `time()`. Why force PHP to do a bunch of pointless string processing when you can get the current timestamp directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is your example code working the way you want.

As others have mentioned, you have to do the math yourself for cases like this.

```
<?php

$now = strtotime("TODAY");
$time_1 = strtotime('08:00:00') - $now;
$total = $time_1 * 5;

$secs = $total%60;
$mins = floor($total/60);
$hours = floor($mins/60);
$mins = $mins%60;

printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $hours, $mins, $secs);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `date()` is intended to produce VALID date/time strings. `40` is not something that would appear in a normal time string. You'll have to use math to generate that time string on your own:

```
$seconds = $total;
$hours = $seconds % 3600;
$seconds -= ($seconds * 3600);
$minutes = $seconds % 60;
$seconds -= ($seconds * 60);

$string = "$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
```

Answer (score 1):

The `date` function is for dates and times, not durations.  Since the time is never "40:00", it will never return that string.

You can look into using [the DateTimeInterface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php) to get what you want, but it might be simpler just to do the math yourself.

```
$seconds = $total;
$minutes = (int)($seconds/60);
$seconds = $seconds % 60;
$hours   = (int)($minutes / 60);
$minutes = $minutes % 60;

$str = "$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
```